# Negative Binomial Transformation

Tags: probability

I really confusing about a transformation of a negative binomial random variable. $X \sim NB(r, p)$. What is the distribution of $Z = X+r$? ($r$ is an integer)

I've try to make $\mathbb{P}(X = x-r)$ and apply that in the pmf of Negative Binomial but without sucess.

What should I proceed to find the pmf of $Z$?